# detection of multiple instances of a object in opencv?

Tags: opencv, object-detection

Does anyone have a suggestion to detect the same object in different places of an image? I have tested the sample/tutorial SURF_Homography, it works to detect only one occurrence of the object. I would like to detect multiple times the same object, in different locations of the image.

Comment: If you have a working single object detector based on SURF, why not just run it, then if you detect the object, delete all the points for that instance of the object and run the remaining points again.  Repeat until there is no positive match.

Comment: But if I have many objects of the same type (for example, 10), it would not be very slow? Anyway, I will test to see how much time it needs.

Comment: The most expensive part should be generating the descriptors and you should only do that once.

Comment: I hope the following suggestions may work for you.
**
1. Run a Sliding Window over the image. In case of object detection we run a sliding window of differnt sizes over the image and Extract features over the patch or window. 

2. Detect the first instance of the object in the test image and the set the region to zeros in the test image and run the algo again to detect the next instance of the object, repeate the process for further stages.**

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion! I will test the sliding window, it may help.

Comment: We have the same problem... have you found any solution? Tks